# Reducing query with multiple “OR” statements in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query with the following terms in php:

```
.
.
elseif ($row['date_starb'] == 0 AND $row['priv_handy'] AND (substr($row['priv_handy'], 0, 4) == '+420' OR substr($row['priv_handy'], 0, 4) == '+421' OR substr($row['priv_handy'], 0, 4) == '+357' OR substr($row['priv_handy'], 0, 4) == '+386'))
.
.
```

This query working, but question is, whether it's possible to easier to write.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question is not clear, can you please explain with more details what actually you want?

Comment: This seems to be a PHP only question. So please remove the mysql tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php) to match against a list of strings:

```
$haysack = ['+420','+421','+357','+386'];
$needle = substr($row['priv_handy'], 0, 4);

if ($row['date_starb'] == 0 AND in_array($needle,$haysack)) {
   // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Came here expecting this to be database, not php - I'm not well up on php but treat this as pseudocode and translate it to php?

I might write something like:

```
AND instr('+420+421+357+386', $row['priv_handy'], 0, 4)
```

Essentially define one string that has all your options in and then search it for your variable contents